# Start conversation on page load

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

I'm a beginner in Java EE 6 and was recently playing with conversations. I was not able to find out how to start conversation immediately as JSF page is loaded (as in Seam). Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doable.

Page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.preRenderView}"/>
        </f:metadata>
        <h:head>
            <title>My Page</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <!-- Body here -->
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    public void preRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
        String currentViewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
        if (CONVERSATION_START_PAGE.equals(currentViewId)) {
            conversation.begin();
    }

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    private static final String CONVERSATION_START_PAGE = "/foo/bar/start-page.xhtml";
}
```